# supress iproute2 error message

Tags: linux, networking, bash, iproute2

iproute2 has a message on fail that I do not know how to suppress.

I want to save the output of iproute2 to a variable for later use.  if my network is up all is well and the output is something like:

```bsh
sudo ip link set wlan0 up
ROUTE=$(ip route get 8.8.8.8)
printf "Route is:\n${ROUTE}"
```

```sh
Route is:
8.8.8.8 via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0 src 192.168.1.17 uid 1000
    cache
```

If my network is down I get an unwanted artifact:

```bsh
sudo ip link set wlan0 down
ROUTE=$(ip route get 8.8.8.8)
printf "Route is:\n${ROUTE}"
```

```sh
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable
Route is:
```

So I am not sure what is producing the message `RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable`, or how to suppress this message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is produced par `ip` on the standard error output.

In your terminal, both standard output and standard error output are printed in the terminal.

With `var=$(command ...)` syntax, you get ony the standard output in the variable but error output will printed by terminal.

You can redirect the error output to trash with `2>/dev/null` after the command. like this:

```
ROUTE=$(ip route get 8.8.8.8 2>/dev/null)
```

Why `2`? On POSIX systems (UNIX and Linux), `1` is the default number for standard output and `2` is for error output. `0` is for standard input.